# Creation of Spring 5 Webclient

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thread-safety, webclient

Whats the best way to create `WebClient` and is it threadsafe?.
I am creating the web client in a spring bean (so there will be only one instance) as below

```
WebClient.builder().baseUrl(consulConfig.getbaseUrl()).build();
```

since its created during bean instantiation, any change to consul config value isn't reflected so we want to create it on every request and wonder if that will have a performance impact.

Comment: Use a `@Bean` method with `@RefreshScope` (assuming you are using Spring Cloud Config to detect changes) you will then get a new instance when needed. The bean is thread safe so you can simply reuse it don't recreate it each time you need one.

Comment: thanks M. Deinum. It worked like magic !!